# PHP usort function returning incorrect results when sorting nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$sort_arr = array(
    array(
        '07',
        '45'
    ),
    array(
        '07',
        '44'
    ),
    array(
        '07',
        '46'
    ),
    array(
        '22',
        '64'
    )
);
```

I need to sort it, in **descending** order, twice, in such a way that the first column takes precedence. To accomplish this, the second column is sorted first, so that when the first column is sorted, it will overwrite the results where appropriate

I created this usort function:

```
$order = array(1, 0);

foreach($order as $col){
    usort($sort_arr, function($a, $b) use ($col){
        return strnatcmp($b[$col], $a[$col]);//b before a - descending order
    });
    var_dump($sort_arr);
}
```

Expected output:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        '22',
        '64'
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '46'
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '45'
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '44'
    }//Result of first sort

array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        '22',
        '64'
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '46'
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '45'
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
        '17',
        '44'
    }//Final result
```

Actual output:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        '22',
        '64'
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '46'
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '45'
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '44'
    }//Result of first sort - correct

array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        '22',
        '64'
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '44'
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '46'
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
        '07',
        '45'
    }//Final result - incorrect
```

PHP Version: 5.6.

On 7.0, the correct result is returned.

I cannot update the PHP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altered @myxaxa's answer to use simple logic instead of funky math.

```
$order = array(1, 0);

usort($sort_arr, function($a, $b) use ($order){
    foreach($order as $col){
        $res = strnatcmp($b[$col], $a[$col]);
        // if the current values are not equal, return
        if( $res !== 0 ) {
            return $res;
        }
        // otherwise keep going
    }
    // if everything's equal we fall out of the loop here and return the last comparison
    return $res;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you having problems because of `If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.` [doc](http://%20https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.) probably smth changed from 5.6 to 7 version of php

to prevent such a mess you can do one-time sort with a hack:

```
<?php

$sort_arr = array(
    array(
        '07',
        '45'
    ),
    array(
        '07',
        '44'
    ),
    array(
        '07',
        '46'
    ),
    array(
        '22',
        '64'
    )
);

$order = array(1, 0);

usort($sort_arr, function($a, $b) use ($order){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($order as $key => $col){
        $sum += strnatcmp($b[$col], $a[$col]) * pow(10, ($key+1));
    }
    return $sum;
});
var_dump($sort_arr);
```

you can check result with different versions [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/o2RwtzFL6H3WrJlV)

some more [data](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69158) about this stuff

Comment: Thanks, that does work. I'll accept your answer if you can give more detail on *why* it works.

Comment: @user5493187 strnatcmp gives you -1, 0, 1 as a result. so you can just use a simple polynomial - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial

Comment: Instead of funky math only continue the loop if `strnatcmp()` returns 0. Will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score -1):

@user5493187, It looks like from your requirements, you are essentially sorting in such a way where the max of each record's column 1 and column 2, is the value to sort based on. If so, here's a solution that is self-documenting without any prior knowledge in advanced subjects:

```
usort($sort_arr, function($a, $b) {

    // Get the max values of a's columns and b's columns, respectfully.

    if ( strnatcmp($a[0], $a[1] ) > 0 ) {
        $a_param = $a[0];
    }
    else {
        $a_param = $a[1]; 
    }

    if ( strnatcmp($b[0], $b[1] ) > 0 ) {
        $b_param = $b[0];
    }
    else {
        $b_param = $b[1]; 
    }

    // Next sort with max value of a's columns and b's columns

    return strnatcmp($a_param, $b_param) * -1;

});
```

Where the `* -1` is for the descending order.

(I'll have to test this in 5.6 if indeed it's usort cant handle a 0 return comparison on ties. php.net seems to say that as of ver 4, usort() hasn't changed in regards to *If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.* So it doesn't appear on face value how this would be of any issue.)

Comment: As this code actually works, i'm curious as to why its a downvote fountain.